Calculate count of rows in sub-query to update parent class in Entity Framework Core
I have two classes, a Parent which can have zero or more Children:
public class Parent()
{
   int ID { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
   int NumberOfChildren { get; set; }
}

and
public class Child()
{
   int ID { get; set; }
   int ParentID { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
}

I am retrieving a list of all Parent records and populating the NumberOfChildren value in the parent using an EF query:
List<Parent> parentList = [];

var tempList = await context.Parents
                            .GroupJoin(context.Children, 
                                       p => p.ID, 
                                       c => c.ParentID, 
                                       (p, c) => new { Parent = p, ChildCount = c.Count() })
                            .ToListAsync();

foreach (var item in tempList)
{
    item.Parent.NumberOfChildren = item.ChildCount;
    parentList.Add(item.Parent);
}

It seems inefficient to have to loop over the result set to update the NumberOfChildren.
Is there a way to set the value of NumberOfChildren in the EF query and have the result assigned directly to the List<Parent> list without the need for such a loop?

Something like that I would leave as a view/consumer consideration. The parent table should not store a denormalized count of children. That value can be computed as needed. If Parent can leverage a collection navigation property for its related Children we have a ParentViewModel which contains a ChildCount property to project at read:
var parents = await context.Parents
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(x => new ParentViewModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        ChildCount = x.Children.Count()
    }).ToListAsync();

A parent entity could have a [NotMapped] property for ChildCount but that would be dependent on the entire Children collection being eager loaded. Otherwise you would trigger a lazy load (if enabled) or return a 0 or incomplete count.

The NumberOfChildren value is NOT stored in the parent table, hence why it is being calculated in the query and being returned in the 'view' of the Parent. I have highly simplified the Parent class, in reality it contains about 20 other properties and I don't want to have to assign each of them to a new view of the parent as you have suggested.

Automapper & Mapperly can manage projections as one-liners supporting EF's IQueryable.  You can opt for the [NotMapped] option with the navigation property but it would only be reliable if the Children are eager-loaded.

Here's single query that you could try out:

Join two tables, produce parent-child pairs
Group by Parent ID, grouping all pairs with the same parent
Select the parent and update also it's children count.

var tempList = await context.Parents
    .Join(context.Children,
               p => p.ID,
               c => c.ParentID,
               (p, c) => new { Parent = p, Child = c })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Parent.ID)
    .Select(x =>
    {
        x.Key.Parent.NumberOfChildren = x.Value.Count();
        return x.Key.Parent;
    });

